# Psexec vs SSH - Executing remote commands from Windows

Tags: php, windows, ssh, psexec

I am currently using PHP `exec` to make use of [Psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to execute commands on a remote machine in my LAN. It sort of works, but I run into trouble every so often and have to google around for an answer, which causes me to make changes.

I will soon have to be executing commands on a remote linux machine as well from windows and I was wondering should I just quit Psexec alltogether and make use of SSH commands from PHP. I haven't used the SSH2 extension before and from the docs it looks like I am going to have problems too due to the fact I am using a windows machine.

But rather than mainting Psexec and [PHP SSH](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) - should try getting PHP SSH2 to work on a windows machine and on the remote windows machine isntall a [SSH server](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/).

Or is there an alternative that I need to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  It's [faster than PHP SSH2](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/#comment_3759) to boot.

Comment: I have gone with the PsExec option for windows and SSH for running commands from windows on a mac/linux box. I'll be making use the suggested library, it works well. Thanks.